# Get Compilation error while using CombiTable1D in OMEdit

Tags: openmodelica

I am trying to use a CombiTable1D in my model

Created a txt file (filename data01.txt)  as  shown below

[image: data01.txt]

and in CombTable1D set parameters as given below

Modelica.Blocks.Sources.CombiTimeTable taba(columns = 2:3, fileName = "C:/Openmod/data01.txt", tableName = "tab1", tableOnFile = true)

Compiling it get this error

... loading "tab1" from "C:/Openmod/data01.txt"

Error in line 5 when reading numeric data of matrix "tab1(3,3)" from file "C:/Openmod/data01.txt"

simulation terminated by an assertion at initialization
Simulation process failed. Exited with code -1.

I am using Open Modelica 1.17 with Modelica 4.0.0 library loaded

THanks

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here. What is your OS language and regionalization?

[image]

The code to read the data is here:
https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaStandardLibrary/blob/master/Modelica/Resources/C-Sources/ModelicaIO.c#L902
and as you can see is using the computer locale to read the data so if you have a locale where "." is "," you should use that.

Comment: Adrian, My OS is Windows 10 and Region is  English (United States) and decimal place is ".".

Comment: But I see there in image you shared , there is block "data.txt" under the Model TestTables. I dont have that . how was that added  ?

Comment: You can just open text files with OMEdit, I opened my own data.txt, in your case: C:/Openmod/data01.txt

Comment: Can you try to change all "." in the data01.txt to "," and see what happens?

Comment: Adrain,I observed that if some text is added at the end , it works fine

Comment: #1
double tab1(3,2)   # comment line
0, 1.5
1, 5.5
2, 4.5
sdss # in a last line